# My water pressure drops to zero from 80 psi when the irrigation system is turned on and never recovers is my prv going out?

Tags: irrigation

Water pressure is 80 psi at the house bib with nothing running. As soon as I activate the sprinkler system it drops to 2-5 psi and never recovers. At the meter it says only 2.8gpm is flowing. Is my pressure regulator going out and should I replace it.

Comment: It sound like you have a leak in a line for the irrigation.  All the water is flowing out of the broken pipe.

Comment: Is this a change, or the way it's always been?